# JsonConverter serialize date field to return number of ticks

Tags: c#, json, serialization

Is there a way to force `JsonConverter` of NewtonSoft to make date time ticks in `"\/Date(number of ticks)\/"` format as `JavascriptSerializer` do ?

```
string resp1 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
    {
        data = collection.Select(r => new
        {
            Date = r.Date,
        })
    }, 
    Formatting.Indented, 
    new JsonSerializerSettings 
    { 
        PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects 
    });
```

**UPDTE1:**

I can do a workaround but I think it is not efficient way.

```
 string resp = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
                    {
                        data = collection.Select(r => new
                        { 
                            Date = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(r.Date).ToString()
                        })
                    }, Formatting.Indented,
                    new JsonSerializerSettings { PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects });
```

Comment: `r.Date.Ticks`, perhaps?

Comment: No `Ticks` is not accessible, `r.Date` is null-able property.

Comment: Okay, then let us know what type it is and give us some sample data to work with.

Comment: It is `DateTime?` , for sample data it can be `DateTime.Now` the main concern is `JavascripSerializer` give something like `"\/Date(1493239380000)\/"` which `JsonConvert` don't, I have used `JsonConvert` to bypass `circular reference exception.

Comment: If it's a `DateTime`, then I still don't understand why you can't just use the `Ticks` property. Even with a `DateTime?` you can still have it be `"/\Date(" + r.Date?.Ticks ?? 0 + ")\/"` or something.

Comment: up+, Sorry I though `Ticks` accessible directly it came from value `r.Date.Value.Ticks` , but still I don't want make anything manually in my opinion this dirty code playing with `string`. but thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [guide on the official site](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DatesInJSON.htm), here they use the example:

```
JsonSerializerSettings microsoftDateFormatSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat
};
string microsoftJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(entry, microsoftDateFormatSettings);
// {"Details":"Application started.","LogDate":"\/Date(1234656000000)\/"}
```

This tells the serializer to store the datetime as ticks.
But you should read the linked information, because there are things you need to know when using the storage format

Comment: No the solution is not `new JavaScriptDateTimeConverter()` but I have resolved by `DateFormatHandling =DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat` setting but `JavaScriptSerializer` give `"\/Date(1493228460000)\/"` while `JsonConverter` give `"\/Date(1493228460000+0430)\/"`

Comment: Anyway your provided link helped me thanks but should learn to read docs of libs before asking anything :))))

Comment: Glad it helped you :)